# Drag and Drop Bitmap and TextView on Canvas- Android

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, drag-and-drop, textview

I am trying to implement the drag and drop functionality in Android. I have a Custom View that overrides the onDraw(Canvas canvas) method to draw a Bitmap on a canvas that acts as my background. Then, I have created it so I can select different colors and paint in this area.

Now, I am trying to add the ability to select photos from the gallery and place them into the canvas. Also, I want to add the ability to create and add textboxes to the canvas area as well. How would I implement this?

I have read through several tutorials looking to create multiple views that are placed in a Canvas, but have not found an example of this being one. Am I understanding the Canvas and View classes incorrectly and is there a simpler way to do this? Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: draw them directly: Canvas.drawBitmap and StaticLayout.draw

Comment: I have looked at some examples, but could you give me one that is more specific to my purposes regarding StaticLayout.draw please?

Comment: whats unclear with Layout.draw(Canvas) ?